# What iPhone push notification services are out there? (Hosted services, not the APNS)

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I'm looking to avoid running my own server all the time when dealing with Apple's push notification service.  From my understanding, I need a constant connection to the APNS which I can't afford...  I was planning on releasing my app for 0.99 or for free and I really don't want to spend a lot of money elsewhere.

After a bit of googling I found sites like http://www.appnotify.com which seems really interesting (and may be a perfect match for me).  Are there any other services similiar to this one out there?

Comment: Just pointing it out that this was recently released as an Open Beta...

Comment: appnotify is not working

Comment: How about using www.pushapps.mobi ? I work for that company, we offer a very cheap and reliable solution

Comment: How about using  http://www.puspapps.mobi ? I work there, we offer a cheap and reliable solution

Answer (score 9):

We found the following services

- [parse.com](http://parse.com)
- [Xtify.com](http://Xtify.com)
- [pushwoosh.com](http://pushwoosh.com)
- [urbanairship.com](http://urbanairship.com)
- [prowlapp.com](http://prowlapp.com)
- [mobdb.net](http://mobdb.net)
- [push.io](http://push.io)
- [Pubnub.com](http://pubnub.com)
- [pushwizard.com](http://pushwizard.com)

They are all different and some of them don't look updated. We have been using parse.com for a while and it works great.

Answer (score 4):

I know of these two: [appNotifications](http://appnotifications.com/), and [urbanairship](http://urbanairship.com/).

Comment: Thumbs up for UrbanAirship - very easy implementation.

Answer (score 3):

there are also these two: [ilime.com](http://www.ilime.com/) and [httpush.com](http://www.httpush.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for [iLime](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/09/30/360idev-denver-ilime-building-the-infrastructure-for-push-in-a/) too.

Comment: From the website: As of July 1, 2011, the iLime API has been discontinued as a public service.

Answer (score 0):

[PushIO](http://www.push.io) has great pricing, nothing on their website, but when I contacted them their pricing was better than most of these.

Comment: it is worst... monthly cost is $99.00, 1,000,000 Pushes for $399... Look at this https://www.mobdb.net/pricing