# What is the easiest way to interact with the APNS Server for sending Push Notifications to iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am running a PHP/MySQL Application on my webserver and I need to send Push Notifications to iOS Devices.

What is the easiest way implementing this? Are they any PHP libraries I can use? Or are there even any service providers in between who will do it for me? (interact with the APNS server)..

What's your experience? How big is the effort to implement Push with PHP?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use an API such as that the following services propose:

1. Choose a Saas API that you will connect to your PHP/MySQL Application

   - Urbanairship
   - Pushwoosh
   - WonderPush
   - Appoxee
   - Pubnub
   - Xtify
   - prowlapp.com
   - mobdb.net
   - push.io
   - appnotifications
   - pushwizard
2. Upload users

   I really recommend to use the SDK proposed by those services because the job they make is significant. They import user devices ID, with other informations such as app opens, behavior events... all you can use for segmenting your user base. Moreover, SDKs are the only way to display rich and in-app messages, and to track conversion.

   But if you really want to do without SDK, you can.

   For example with [WonderPush Notifications](https://www.wonderpush.com)  API, because I know this one, you have to make the two following calls. 
   You need first to login (it takes one second, it doesnt required credit card !) create your app and grab your client id.

   Then for each device, you just need to make the two following requests:

   ```
   curl -XPOST https://api.wonderpush.com/v1/authentication/accessToken \
       -d clientId=YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID \
       -d devicePlatform=iOS \
       -d deviceId=DEVICE_ID

   curl -XPATCH https://api.wonderpush.com/v1/installation \
       -d accessToken=TOKEN_FROM_PREVIOUS_CALL \
       -d body='{"pushToken":{"data":{"DEVICE_PUSH_TOKEN"}}}'
   ```
3. Notify your users

   This example is just for simple notification. You can go further with many advanced features, like HTML in app messages, custom events...

   ```
   curl -XPOST https://api.wonderpush.com/v1/management/deliveries \
       -d accessToken=SERVER_PRIVATE_ACCESS_TOKEN \
       -d applicationId=YOUR_APP_ID \
       -d segmentIds=@ALL \
       -d notificationOverride='{"type":"simple","text":"Hello, that's my message!","data":{"type":"simple"}}'
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There's a previous question about [hosted APNS services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487161/what-iphone-push-notification-services-are-out-there-hosted-services-not-the-a); however, some of those services now appear to be defunct.

Two current services seem to be [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) and [iLime](http://www.ilime.com/).  Both offer free service up to a certain number of messages.  I haven't (yet) used either so I cannot comment on how well they work, but I do know Urban Airship has been around since the early days of APNS which is a bit reassuring..