# send push notification once new building data is added

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am creating iPhone app where I want to send notification to users who have my app. When admin login add some building, I want to send push notification. (not by going to push notification website and then sending manually)

Any idea how to get this done?

I am new to push notification.

Comment: what are you talking about : "who have myApp when admin through login add some building." ?!

Comment: Could you please describe it little clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For push notification., get register yourself here..

[Urban Airship](https://go.urbanairship.com/accounts/register/)

[Tutorial Link](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3a+iOS%3a+Push)

This website is providing to send push notification for our app.
I've also implemented this in my app.

Enjoy. happy coding. Thanks

Comment: Do I need to do payment at Urban for push notification?

Comment: no not necessary., first 200 push notification is free per app. if we need further then only need to pay. @FahimParkar

Comment: ohh... 200 are not enough... I heard someone have free push notification till 1 millions.

Comment: ohh.. can you tell me which site is providing this? Beacause i've implemented UrbanAirship notification functionality in my app, around 6 months ago. till the date m not aware about this, that we can get free bunches of push notifications.@FahimParkar

Comment: one question... i have real estate app. if i add building in my db through iphone app, how can i send push notification? do i have to send push notification manually (seperately?)

Comment: check http://www.pushwoosh.com/accounts-comparison/ (1 million are free)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487161/what-iphone-push-notification-services-are-out-there-hosted-services-not-the

Comment: I implemented urban (except I didnt make account for production). also ignored "DEVELOPMENT_APP_KEY" = "Your development app key";
        "DEVELOPMENT_APP_SECRET" = "Your development app secret"; Still I dnt get push notification.

Comment: have you download certificate from your developer account? once you 've downloaded it then upload it in airship? have you followed this tutorial? @FahimParkar https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3a+iOS%3a+Push

Comment: when you adding new data in database you can send push notification. for that first of all you have to activate "Allow Push From Device" for your app. refer this post :: @FahimParkar  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592762/urban-airship-send-push-with-nsurlconnection

Comment: I got reply from Urban as `-Our Developer Edition is free and includes up to one million notifications per month. Each message in excess of 1M is billed at $.001. Rich Push messages are billed at ($.0025 per message, there is no free RP).` Means I can send 1M for free?

Comment: I did everything as per documentation. But still I don't get notification message. At start itself it don't ask for Notification setting... any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I am confused at this line now "Register Your Device, 2. Add the application to your phone." means what? I believe I need to add `3. Obj C Implementation` part in my app delegate method.

Comment: it means you have to register your device unique number on the site., so that they can recognize particular device for send push notification, and for that you also have to install same app as you have created in urban airship's website in your device. (according to your app key). @FahimParkar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26623/discussion-between-fahim-parkar-and-dhruvik)